# IVP with locally defined solution in $C^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $J\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Lets suppose that the IVP $\dot x = f(t,x)$, $x(t_{0})=x_{0}$ with $f\in C(J \times \mathbb{R})$ and $(t,x)\in J \times \mathbb{R}$ has a solution in $C^{1}$ defined locally in time for all initial data in $(t_{0},x_{0}) \in J\times \mathbb{R}$. Show that if the maximum interval of definition for a solution $x(t)$ is $(T_{-},T_{+}) \subset J$ then $lim_{x\downarrow T_{-}} |x(t)| = \infty$ and $lim_{x\uparrow T_{+}} |x(t)| = \infty$ .

Alright, the thing is that this, as my first course of ODE's is getting pretty hard. I can solve the problems which involves calculating stuff but for proofs im not really trained :/ any help would be really appreciated <3

Thanks in advance guys <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that 
$$\limsup_{t \to T_+} \vert x(t) \vert = +\infty$$
does not hold. In particular, $x$ is bounded on a neighbourhood of $T_+$, and using the fact that $x^\prime(t) = f(t,x(t))$ and $f$ is continuous, $x^\prime$ is also bounded on a neighbourhood of $T_+$.

Using the mean value theorem and the Cauchy criterion shows that $x(t)$ has a finite limit $x_+$ when $t \to T_+$ *(EDIT: see below for more details)*.

Consider now $(T_+,x_+)$ as a new initial condition and denote $y$ its maximal solution on the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\beta > T_+$. We can construct a new solution $X$ such that $X(t) = x(t)$ on $(T_-,T_+]$ and $X(t) = y(t)$ on $(T_+,\beta)$, this contradicts the fact that $x$ is a maximal solution.

*EDIT: More details.* The mean value theorem tells that 
$$\vert x(t_1) - x(t_2) \vert \leq \left(\sup_{t \in [t_1,t_2]} \vert x^\prime(t) \vert\right)\vert t_1 - t_2\vert$$ 
for $t_1,t_2$ near $T_+$ and the fact that $x^\prime$ is bounded near $T_+$ shows that it exists $C \geq 0$ such that 
$$\vert x(t_1) - x(t_2) \vert \leq C \vert t_1 - t_2\vert $$
for $t_1,t_2$ near $T_+$.
Now the Cauchy criterion tells us the following (see [Cauchy condition for functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419909/cauchy-condition-for-functions) for more details)

> A function $g$ has a limit at $a$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ and $0<|y-a|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$.

Applying this with $g = x$ and $a=T_+$ shows that $x$ has a finite limit at $t = T_+$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your asnwer, but could you please elaborate the part where you use the mean value theorem.
And for Cauchy criterion is the same as Picard Lindelof? Ill give you the bountie price as soon as the page let me haha.

Comment: I will edit my post to give more informations.

Comment: Thanks so much! Im approximately 11 hours the bounty is yours haha. I finally understood this problem. <3

Comment: Feel free to do it whenever you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume one of the limits is a finite number. Construct a contradiction to the maximality of $(T_-, T_+)$.